# c# datagridview one way binding

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `datagridview DGV1` I want to read from an XML file and bind DGV1 to it 
but once changes are made in DGV1 I want it to to be stored in a list 
somthing like file.

```
XML --> DGV1 --> list
```

what I have tried now is menioned below

```
    public DataTable PopulateDGV1()
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(GlobalParam.SettingsXMLPath);
        return dataSet.Tables[0];
    }

    private void LoadDGV1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DGV1.DataSource = _control.PopulateDGV1();
        if (DGV1.Columns[0] != null) DGV1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;//make the most left column read only 

    }
```

I want somthing of this sort fro the save

```
    List<string> data = new List<String>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in DGV1.Rows)
    {
        if (item.Cells[1].Value!=null)
        data.Add(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString());

    }
```

what am I missing here ?

Comment: Your code looks OK. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: @HerrKater I want it to happen without prompting the user to actually save it , like bindinglist(I think) but one-direction

Comment: Why do you want to maintain 2 collections(DataTable, and List), which representing the same thing? I would create a class which represents a row, and use it as the datasource for the grid. If the user edits the grid, it automatically updates the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<Test> DataSource;

    public void PopulateDGV1()
    {
        DataSource=new List<Test>() { new Test() { Age = 2, Name = "Test" } };
        //TODO:read your XML file
        DGV1.DataSource = DataSource;
    }

    private void LoadDGV1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateDGV1();
    }

}

public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```